# Aggregates and grouping

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, aggregate

trying to do some analytics on my MongoDB collection using my .NET Core project. (C# driver)

My problem is with aggregating and grouping by multiple fields, and by and nested array element field.

For starters, heres as simplified as I can document example -

```
{
  "_id": ".....",
  "CampaignId": 1,
  "IsTest":false
  "Events": [
    {
      "EventId": 1,
      "IsFake": false
    },
    {
      "EventId": 1,
      "IsFake": true
    }
    {
      "EventId": 2,
      "IsFake": false
    }
  ]
}
```

My end goal, is to generate an analytics report that will look like this for example-

```
[
  {
    "CampaignId": 1,
    "DocumentCountReal":17824,
    "DocumentCountTest":321,
    "EventCountReal":100,
    "EventCountFake":5,
    "Events": [
      {
        "EventId": 1,
        "IsFake": false,
        "Count": 50
      },
      {
        "EventId": 1,
        "IsFake": true,
        "Count": 5
      },
      {
        "EventId": 2,
        "IsFake": false,
        "Count": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CampaignId": 2,
    "DocumentCountReal":1314,
    "DocumentCountTest":57,
    "EventCountReal":50,
    "EventCountFake":0,
    "Events": [
      {
        "EventId": 1,
        "IsFake": false,
        "Count": 25
      },
      {
        "EventId": 2,
        "IsFake": false,
        "Count": 25
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Just to show you where I currently stand, I found out how to group by one field lol...
Example -

```
var result = collection.Aggregate().Group(c => c.CampaignId, r => new { CampaignId= r.Key, Count = r.Count()}).ToList();
```

Couldn't find how to group by a nested array element field (in the example the `IsFake` property in Event) and in general to build a result as I shared above.
To my surprise I couldn't find a lot of related questions in google.. (specifically using c# driver)

Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: Take a look `$facet` operator to execute several aggregations in one stage

Answer (score 0):

So, found a partial solution eventually, thought I'll share - 
The biggest problem was to group by a property of a nested array (In my initial question it was the Event array).
In order to achieve that I used Unwind (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
FYI - I needed to use the PreserveNullAndEmptyArrays option in order to not miss documents that had no event.
Also, I made an extra class where the `Events` property is a single Event instead of a list, that is to deserialize the document after Uwind is being used.

My second question was how to perform several aggregations in one trip to the database, as Valijon commented it looks like `$facet` is required, couldn't find an example that fits my question.

Example of my solution -

```
            IMongoDatabase db = MongoDBDataLayer.NewConnection();
            IMongoCollection<Click> collection = db.GetCollection<Click>("click");

            var unwindOption = new AggregateUnwindOptions<ClickUnwinded>() { PreserveNullAndEmptyArrays = true };


            var result = collection.Aggregate().Unwind<Click, ClickUnwinded>(c => c.Events, unwindOption)
                .Group(
                //group by
                c => new GroupByClass()
                {
                    CampaignId = c.CampaignId,
                    IsTest = c.IsTest,
                    EventId = c.Events.EventId,
                    IsRobot = c.UserAgent.IsRobot
                },
                r => new GroupResultClass()
                {
                    CampaignId = r.First().CampaignId,
                    IsTest = r.First().IsTest,
                    EventId = r.First().Events.EventId,
                    IsRobot = r.First().UserAgent.IsRobot,
                    Count = r.Count()
                }
                ).ToList();
```

If anyone has an example of how to uttilize facet using c# driver that would be great.

edit - 
So, the problem is that doing the approach above will count the same document multiple times if the document have multiple events ... so I have to either find a way to multi aggregate (first aggregate must happen before the unwind) or to make 2 trips to the db.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51356856/4368485) will help